# Invoking Windows Workflow Service using HttpClient?

Tags: asp.net-core, httpclient, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, .net-core

I have Windows Workflow Service developed in 4.6.2.

Is it possible to Invoke Window Workflow Service using HttpClient?

I have client application in `.Net Core`, and we cannot create WF service proxy in `.Net Core` application. (It's not supported currently)

However .net core has HttpClient class and I would like to know if can use HttpClient to invoke methods of Windows Workflow Service?

Comment: Did you checked https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/05/25/announcing-wcf-connected-service-for-net-core-rc2-and-asp-net-core-rc2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a VS extension for generating your proxy https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/06/26/wcf-connected-service-for-net-core-1-0-0-and-asp-net-core-1-0-0-is-now-available/